# Kentico - Bootstrap carousel to hide controller if there's only one item

Tags: kentico

I'm implementing a bootstrap 3 carousel on kentico 9 and need some help with automatically hiding the carousel control (including the circle indicator and the next/previous arrow) if there's only one item left, if possible.

What I've done for the carousel was setting up a new page type for this in which each banner is a page in the content tree under /hero/ folder. Then used 2 repeaters: the first one displays the circle indicator; the second one displays the banner info. All worked well.

Here's how the indicator repeater is set up:

```
Content before: <ol class="carousel-indicators">
Content after </ol>
Item transformation: <li data-target="#hero-banner" data-slide-to="<%# DataItemIndex%>" class="<%# (DataItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "" ) %>"></li>
```

It means the first circle is always there. How to hide it and get rid of the `<ol>` tags in content before/after?

The next/previous arrows are again in the webpart zone content after, which has this html:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#hero-banner" data-slide="prev"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#hero-banner" data-slide="next"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
</div>   <!--/#hero-banner-->
```

Using content before/after is like hard-coding it onto the page, but I don't know how to make it displayed dynamically and automatically only when we have more than one item. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `<%# DataItemCount %>` One of the [Transformation methods][1]

[1]: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Reference+-+Transformation+methods to determine how many items there are. Then just have the html added in if there is more than one. Something like

```
<%# If(DataItemCount > 1,'html for more than one item','html for only one') %>
```

Of course, if you are using the envelope before / after to show arrows, you could also use jquery to determine how many items are there & hide the arrows based off that.

```
$(function(){    
  if($(".carousel-indicators li").length == 1){
       $(".left.carousel-control").hide();
       $(".right.carousel-control").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so into Kentico and forgot about jquery in terms of displaying the stuff in content before/after :) . Much appreciated!